# symfony2 many to many with a unique tag name

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tags, many-to-many

I am making a simple article and tags system for my application, with a many to many relation, I followed [the Form Collections tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and all works fine.

The problem with this tutorial is that the form will create a new tag even if there is another tag with the same name.

When I add a "unique:true" constraints to the "name" column in Tag Entity, for preventing duplication, I get this exception :

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'News' for key 'UNIQ_CF8E3B185E237E06'`

Is there any way to get a unique tag name in this kind of relation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before applying the unique declaration in your YML, look for duplicate entries in your database, and get rid of them.